# gcovr not showing code coverage for untouched header files

Tags: c++, code-coverage, gcov, lcov, gcovr

I have the following structure for a header only library

```
include
  - header1.h
  - header2.h
  - header3.h
test
  - test1.cpp
```

Now `test1.cpp` only uses `header1.h`, so when I compile `test1.cpp` with `--coverage` option, run the test, and then run `gcovr` to generate the report (with `-r ../include` from test directory), it only shows me coverage for `header1.h`.
I want to show coverage of 0% for `header2.h` and `header3.h` also, because it represents a more accurate representation of code covered by tests.

Comment: (1) Code in header files may be inlined and therefore this is no code to execute that would generate a coverage report. And (2)  _"...so when I compile test1.h..."_ why are you compiling header files ?

Comment: for your (2) point, I have edited the question, it is `test1.cpp`

Answer (score 1):

Coverage data is collected per compilation unit. In your example, you have one compilation unit for the `test1.cpp` file. The compiler will generate a .gcno file that allows other tools to associate coverage data with lines in the files in this compilation unit. But since only `header1.h` was included, there will not be any such information in the .gcno file about header2 and header3.

Coverage tools like gcov and gcovr are language-agnostic, and do not search your directories for files that *might* contain uncovered source code. If you want the coverage report to know about the files, you must include the file in a compilation unit that you compile with `--coverage`. Even then, you will note that GCC ignores inline functions that were not called. You can only get coverage data when machine code was generated for that code.

This is a fundamental limitation of the gcov coverage mechanism, and means that you have to take care when interpreting coverage metrics for header files. Do not mistake a high coverage percentage to mean that everything that could be covered also was covered – it merely means that the machine code generated for code in that file was thoroughly exercised.